# How make last window open not go to bottom of inactive windows

Tags: windows-10

How do I make windows 10 not push last window open not go to bottom of inactive windows? I have an application that it's icon is in a folder on the desktop. If I open the folder and open the application it stays on top. Then if I choose an option in the application that opens a result file in Notepad, the application main window is now hidden beneath the File Explorer window, which means I then have to click the application icon again to see it. It seems that it used to didn't be this way on my system. Seems like I could choose the option in the application (which opens the results in Notepad), then just close Notepad, and I would then see my application as the active window on  top. Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Yeah. Windows 10 is finicky like that. Grin and bear.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping maybe a registry setting could correct that.

Comment: A registry setting that makes Windows do what it is _supposed_ to do normally? Everyone wants that... ;)